# Scripts Load Before Blazor WebAssembly App Renders Inside

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I'm encountering an issue where it seems that all the script tags within my Blazor WebAssembly app are being loaded before the app content renders. Here's the HTML structure of my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fa" class="light-style layout-menu-fixed" dir="rtl" data-theme="theme-default" data-assets-path="assets/" data-template="horizontal-menu-template-no-customizer">
<head>
    <!-- ... (head content) ... -->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">loading...</div>

    <!-- ... (other divs and error UI) ... -->

    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>

    <!-- ... (other script tags) ... -->
</body>
</html>
```

The problem I'm facing is that all the script tags within the body are loading before the actual content of the  is rendered. This includes scripts that are critical for my Blazor app's functionality.

I expected that the Blazor app content would render first and then the scripts would load, but it seems like the opposite is happening. Is there a way to ensure that the Blazor app renders first before the scripts are loaded?

I've tried moving the script tags around and changing their order, but I haven't been able to find a solution. Any insights into how to ensure proper script loading order in a Blazor WebAssembly app would be greatly appreciated.
notice: All Js files are included in wwwroot folder
Thank you!